# Return the number of elements of an array that is the most "expensive"

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I recently stumbled upon an interesting problem, an I am wondering if my solution is optimal.

> You are given an array of zeros and ones. The goal is to return the
>   amount zeros and the amount of ones in the most expensive sub-array.
>
> The cost of an array is the amount of 1s divided by amount of 0s. In
>   case there are no zeros in the sub-array, the cost is zero.

1. At first I tried brute-forcing, but for an array of 10,000 elements it was far too slow and I ran out of memory.
2. My second idea was instead of creating those sub-arrays, to remember the start and the end of the sub-array. That way I saved a lot of memory, but the complexity was still O(n<sup>2</sup>).
3. My final solution that I came up is I think O(n). It goes like this:

   Start at the beginning of the array, for each element, calculate the cost of the sub-arrays starting from 1, ending at the current index. So we would start with a sub-array consisting of the first element, then first and second etc. Since the only thing that we need to calculate the cost, is the amount of 1s and 0s in the sub-array, I could find the optimal end of the sub-array.

   The second step was to start from the end of the sub-array from step one, and repeat the same to find the optimal beginning. That way I am sure that there is no better combination in the whole array.

   Is this solution correct? If not, is there a counter-example that will show that this solution is incorrect?

#### Edit

For clarity:
Let's say our input array is 0101.
There are 10 subarrays:
0,1,0,1,01,10,01,010,101 and 0101.

The cost of the most expensive subarray would be 2 since 101 is the most expensive subarray. So the algorithm should return 1,2

#### Edit 2

There is one more thing that I forgot, if 2 sub-arrays have the same cost, the longer one is "more expensive".

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to know the number of 1 and 0 in an array?

Comment: Wouldn't the most expensive sub-array always contain only one zero with all the adjacent ones to its left and right?

Comment: @digEmAll yes the second solution is still O(n^2), it just saved memory since it did not create new sub-arrays

Comment: Also... do the sub-arrays contain consecutive elements of the main array ?

Comment: @digEmAll yes they do

Comment: @halfbit no, since there could be no single ones in the array for example 01100.

Comment: @DogDog I need to know the number of 0s and 1s in the most expensive subarray of an array.

Comment: added an example for clarity

Comment: why not 2,2 ? 0101 has two zeros too

Comment: You can simplify the problem by simply counting runs of 1s and 0s, then calculating their ratios on both sides, then finding the max ratio.  That would take you down to an O(n) solution, with 3 passes, I think.

Comment: @MillerKoijam no, since the cost of your array is 2/2 = 1, which is smaller than 101 which is 2/1 = 2

Comment: @Joel could you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: That solution actually only works if we can prove that the max array should look like 1+,0+,1+ (except the degenerate case, of course)

Comment: Can you give an example of a (not all 1) array with a most expensive sub-array not matching `1*01*` or `1*001*` (where on the latter one the number of 1s are equal on left and right)? (The 00 case would account for the new the-longer-the-higher-the-cost rule)

Comment: @halfbit you might have hit the jackpot. I have examined arrays such as this 1*01+01* and it seems that all the maximal subarrays are given by your pattern. But what does that give us?

Comment: i have also found that if array given by 1*0{3}0*1* will always have the max from one part of the array.
Example: 1{n}0001{n} the part array would cost n while the whole array would cost 2n/3, and there is no n that makes the whole array more expensive.

Comment: It would give us a starting point for an algorithm which would only need to sweep once over the array, remembering the best 1*0*1* and working with the current 1*0*1* sequence. Current position and run lengths would be enough; complexity O(n). Ill post an impl in Java which you might try.

Comment: That's my approach below. Be sure to account for the edge conditions exposed in the counterexample there 10011.  The correct answer is 011, not the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sketch a proof for my assumption:

(a = whole array, `*`=zero or more, `+`=one or more, `{n}`=exactly n)

Cases `a=0*` and `a=1+` : c=0

Cases `a=01+` and `a=1+0` : conforms to `1*0{1,2}1*`, a is optimum

```
For the normal case, a contains one or more 0s and 1s.
This means there is some optimum sub-array of non-zero cost.
(S) Assume s is an optimum sub-array of a.
It contains one or more zeros. (Otherwise its cost would be zero).
(T) Let t be the longest `1*0{1,2}+1*` sequence within s 
(and among the equally long the one with with most 1s).
(Note: There is always one such, e.g. `10` or `01`.)
Let N be the number of 1s in t.
Now, we prove that always t = s.
By showing it is not possible to add adjacent parts of s to t if (S).
(E) Assume t shorter than s.
We cannot add 1s at either side, otherwise not (T).
For each 0 we add from s, we have to add at least N more 1s 
later to get at least the same cost as our `1*0+1*`.
This means: We have to add at least one run of N 1s.
If we add some run of N+1, N+2 ... somewhere than not (T).
If we add consecutive zeros, we need to compensate 
with longer runs of 1s, thus not (T).
This leaves us with the only option of adding single zeors and runs of N 1s each.
This would give (symmetry) `1{n}*0{1,2}1{m}01{n+m}...`
If m>0 then `1{m}01{n+m}` is longer than `1{n}0{1,2}1{m}`, thus not (T).
If m=0 then we get `1{n}001{n}`, thus not (T).
So assumption (E) must be wrong.
```

Conclusion: The optimum sub-array must conform to `1*0{1,2}1*`.

Here is my O(n) impl in Java according to the assumption in my last comment (`1*01*` or `1*001*`):

```
public class Q19596345 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String array = "0101001110111100111111001111110";
            System.out.println("array=" + array);
            SubArray current = new SubArray();
            current.array = array;
            SubArray best = (SubArray) current.clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                current.accept(array.charAt(i));
                SubArray candidate = (SubArray) current.clone();
                candidate.trim();
                if (candidate.cost() > best.cost()) {
                    best = candidate;
                    System.out.println("better: " + candidate);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("best: " + best);
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(System.err); }
    }
    static class SubArray implements Cloneable {
        String array;
        int start, leftOnes, zeros, rightOnes;

        // optimize 1*0*1* by cutting
        void trim() {
            if (zeros > 1) {
                if (leftOnes < rightOnes) {
                    start += leftOnes + (zeros - 1);
                    leftOnes = 0;
                    zeros = 1;
                } else if (leftOnes > rightOnes) {
                    zeros = 1;
                    rightOnes = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        double cost() {
            if (zeros == 0) return 0;
            else return (leftOnes + rightOnes) / (double) zeros + 
                (leftOnes + zeros + rightOnes) * 0.00001;
        }
        void accept(char c) {
            if (c == '1') {
                if (zeros == 0) leftOnes++;
                else rightOnes++;
            } else {
                if (rightOnes > 0) {
                    start += leftOnes + zeros;
                    leftOnes = rightOnes;
                    zeros = 0;
                    rightOnes = 0;
                }
                zeros++;
            }
        }
        public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { return super.clone(); }
        public String toString() { return String.format("%s at %d with cost %.3f with zeros,ones=%d,%d", 
            array.substring(start, start + leftOnes + zeros + rightOnes), start, cost(), zeros, leftOnes + rightOnes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can show the max array is always 1+0+1+, 1+0, or 01+ (Regular expression notation then we can calculate the number of runs

So for the array (010011), we have (always starting with a run of 1s)

0,1,1,2,2

so the ratios are (0, 1, 0.3, 1.5, 1), which leads to an array of 10011 as the final result, ignoring the one runs

Cost of the left edge is 0
Cost of the right edge is 2

So in this case, the right edge is the correct answer -- 011

I haven't yet been able to come up with a counterexample, but the proof isn't obvious either.  Hopefully we can crowd source one :)

The degenerate cases are simpler
All 1's and 0's are obvious, as they all have the same cost.
A string of just 1+,0+ or vice versa is all the 1's and a single 0.

Comment: How do you calculate the ratios?

Comment: add the neighbors and divide by the center (or vice versa, for 1s)

Comment: the final result is incorrect, since the correct answer is 011 which is of cost 2, as opposed to yur result which has a cost of 3/2

Comment: The key seems to be that adding more 0s is always bad.  Hence the 101 pattern.  On the edges, though that can be wrong.  Perhaps just counting the ones there is the right way to go.  The other monkey wrench is looking for the longest sequence.  I've found sequences where the whole is equal to a subsequence.

Comment: its not always bad, if there are many more ones on the other side. Example: 1111001111. As you can see all the maximal sub-arrays have a value of 4, but we should return 2,8 since this is the longest one.

Comment: That's a 101 pattern, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40021/discussion-between-joel-and-bartlomiej-lewandowski)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? As a C# programmer, I am thinking we can use something like Dictionary of `<int,int,int>.`
The first int would be use as key, second as subarray number and the third would be for the elements of sub-array.

For your example
key|Sub-array number|elements

```
   1|1|0
   2|2|1
   3|3|0
   4|4|1
   5|5|0
   6|5|1
   7|6|1
   8|6|0
   9|7|0
   10|7|1
   11|8|0
   12|8|1
   13|8|0
   14|9|1
   15|9|0
   16|9|1
   17|10|0
   18|10|1
   19|10|0
   20|10|1
```

Then you can run through the dictionary and store the highest in a variable.

```
var maxcost=0
var arrnumber=1;
var zeros=0;
var ones=0;
var cost=0;
for (var i=1;i++;i<=20+1)
{
    if ( dictionary.arraynumber[i]!=dictionary.arraynumber[i-1])
    {
       zeros=0;
       ones=0;
       cost=0;
       if (cost>maxcost)
       {
           maxcost=cost;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dictionary.values[i]==0)
        {
          zeros++; 
        }
        else
        {
         ones++;
        }
        cost=ones/zeros;
    }

}
```

This will be log(n^2), i hope and u just need 3n size of memory of the array?

Comment: a dictionary with many values to one key? How would run through such a structure to find the most expensive subarray? Could you give an example?

Comment: Also, you still have to calculate all the subarrays, which is O(2^n)

Comment: it seems that my second approach is similar, but there is no need to store all of the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can modify the [maximal subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) to fit to this question. Here's my attempt at it:

```
void FindMaxRatio(int[] array, out maxNumOnes, out maxNumZeros)
{
    maxNumOnes = 0;
    maxNumZeros = 0;
    int numOnes = 0;
    int numZeros = 0;
    double maxSoFar = 0;
    double maxEndingHere = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.Size; i++){
        if(array[i] == 0) numZeros++;
        if(array[i] == 1) numOnes++;
        if(numZeros == 0) maxEndingHere = 0;
        else maxEndingHere = numOnes/(double)numZeros;
        if(maxEndingHere < 1 && maxEndingHere > 0) {
            numZeros = 0;
            numOnes = 0;
        }
        if(maxSoFar < maxEndingHere){
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
            maxNumOnes = numOnes;
            maxNumZeros = numZeros;
        }          
    }
}
```

I think the key is if the ratio is less then 1, we can disregard that subsequence because
there will always be a subsequence `01` or `10` whose ratio is 1. This seemed to work for `010011`.